# Make div keeps visible while hovering it css

Tags: css

I'm having a **shopping cart icon** and **shopping cart div** that works like this:

*Cart icon hovering* --> (show the cart div resume).

The problem is that you mouse leave the cart icon and the cart div resume disappears. I'm trying adjust this in css but I only make it worst :S

My desire result is that:

- Div cart resume appears while you make hover in cart icon. (WORK)
- Div cart resumen keeps visible while you make hover in cart resume div.(FAIL)

Any idea to work with this or some similar. You can see my structure in the next fiddle.

Mainly css is this:

```
.header-cart-toggle .widget_shopping_cart{
    visibility:hidden;
    opacity:0;
    position:absolute;
    margin:0;
    right:0;
    z-index: 1;
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    transition:visibility 0s ease 0s, opacity 0.5s ease;
    -webkit-transition:visibility 0s ease 0s, opacity 0.5s ease;
}
.header-cart-toggle:hover .widget_shopping_cart{
    visibility:visible;
    opacity:1;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    transition-delay:0s;
    -webkit-transition-delay:0s;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/z0hygw7w/

Answer (score 1):

In fact, I see on hover on the cart or on the menu, the menu is visible.  header-menu-icons has width 100% and height 18px, so maybe you want to increase the height of the icon or move the menu closer to the icon.

A second option would be to replace the hover effect with onclick action. The name of the class, "`header-cart-toggle`" suggest me that you may want a toggle effect.